# create div with content from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have:

```
arrayofobj = [
    {
        property: "string",   // "card" object with different data types
        property2: integer
    },
    {
        property: "string",   // "card" object with different data types
        property2: integer
    },
    {
        //etc more cards
    }
];

var playDeck = arrayofobj.slice(0);//creates copy of deck to "use" for game
shuffled(playDeck);//shuffles deck
playerHand = [];//empty array to save cards into
deal10(playDeck);//removes the 1st 10 out of playDeck and puts in playerHand
```

Now from the 10 that get drawn into `playerHand`, I'm trying to display them on screen. I have a `field` set up with:

```
<div id="playerHand"></div>
```

My attempt which hasn't been very successful:

```
for (var i = 0; i < playerHand.length; i++) {
    content = playerHand[i];
    x = document.getElementById('playerHand').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    x.className = 'card' + [i];
    document.getElementsByClassName('card' + [i]).textContent = content;
}
```

I haven't been able to achieve the desired effect. I'm a beginner as far as programming goes so I'm open to constructive criticism. So if you haven't gathered already what I'm trying to do is display each object or `card` on the screen as its own div (so that I can add click handlers to them and have the clicked one played on the screen... for example.)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `player1Hand` as ID instead of `playerHand` then? in your HTML?

Comment: `document.getElementById('player1Hand')..` Is this ID name correct?

Comment: it is -.- 

just changed it for readability... sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an array and not the actual reference to the element. See below:

```
var data, content, container, element;

container = document.getElementById('container');
data = [
    {
        name: "stringa"
    },
    {
        name: "stringb"
    }
];


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Are you accessing an actual property in your code? It seems
    // you are just referencing the whole object.
    content = data[ i ].name;

    // Just save the createElement reference ;)
    element = document.createElement('div');

    // Why are you appending [i] instead of i directly?
    element.className = 'card' + i;

    // By saving the element directly we don't have to query for
    // the class in this step. The other problem was probably that
    // `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you would have
    // to call:                                      vvv
    // document.getElementsByClassName('card' + [i])[ 0 ]
    element.textContent = content;

    container.appendChild( element );
}
```

Obligatory JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgtefsrm/1/

Comment: <3 you're a legend. that worked perfectly. as the whole object and with properties. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Glad you are happy :-) Don't forget to mark the correct answer on your questions!